# Редактор CKEditor

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Для редактирования текстов на сайте у нас используется wisiwig редактор [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). Сейчас возникла необходимость сделать так, чтобы всем абзацам проставлялся опред. класс. Никак не могу разобраться, где это можно настроить. И еще надо переопределить стиль некот. заголовков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант, без вмешательства в редактор - обернуть вывод редактора в какой-нибудь див и в CSS прописать:

```
div.ckedit p { /* ... */ }
div.ckedit h1 { /* ... */ }
```

Чтобы эти стили было видно в редакторе нужно посмотреть, во что обёрнуто окошко редактора, и подключить аналогичные стили:

```
tinyMCE.init
(
    {
        content_css : "ваши_стили.css",
        /* ... */ 
    }
);
```

Второй вариант. Создаём отдельную кнопку для работы с выделенными блоками текста (styleselect):

```
tinyMCE.init
(
    {
        theme_advanced_buttons1 :"styleselect,...",
        /* ... */ 
        style_formats : 
        [
            {title : 'P test', block : 'p', classes : 'pppp'},
        /* ... */
        ]
    }
);
```

Соответственно, в подключаемом к редактору content_css прописываем p.pppp, чтобы этот стиль был виден в редакторе. Выделяем абзац мышкой, выбираем "P test" и получаем параграф с классом "pppp". Но это уже будет на совести юзеров :)

Comment: Спасибо, но там просто ведь и в окошке редактирования все стили применяются, т.е. пользователи могут запутаться.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Что-то совсем запарился: хотел про CK, а автоматом написал про tinymce, потому что его больше использую :) В общем, там аналогично :)